# How can I get next element in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, increment

I have a list with a lot of `bool` values in it and I want to get this pattern: `True, True, False, True, True`. To do this I think I need to get the next element in a loop while processing my previous element. How can I do it?

Bonus question: Is there a way to increment the position of an element in a list other than `i += 1` thing?

Comment: Bonus answer: `enumerate()`. Read the docs ;)

Comment: Actually, `for i in range(len(somelist))` is enough to answer the bonus question, since it avoids the explicit `i += 1`. But it still means you need an unnecessary `somelist[i]`, which is exactly the point of `enumerate`, so +1 to Joel Cornett. (Or can I just enumerate him?)

Comment: Actually, the problem as stated doesn't seem to need to look at any elements: `def getThisPattern(listWithALotOfValuesInit): return (True, True, False, True, True)`. Is the actual problem the equivalent of `str.find`, but for `list` instead?

Answer (score 2):

I'll have a stab at:

```
subset = [True, True, False, True, True]
main = [False, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True]

for i, j in  enumerate(xrange(len(subset), len(main) + 1)):
    if main[i:j] == subset:
        print subset, 'is at', i
        break
else:
    print 'not found'
```

**note**: this is a bit brute forceish, but okay for one-offs... otherwise, look at tries...

Answer (score 1):

```
l = len(some_list) - 3
for i, thing in enumerate(some_list):
    if i == l: break
    if thing and some_list[i+1] and not some_list[i+2] and some_list[i+3]:
        bingo(i)
```

Another untested try:

```
needle = [True, True, False, True, True]
needle_len = len(needle)
for i in range(len(stack)-needle_len+1):
    if needle == stack[i:i+needle_len]:
        bingo(i)
```

Comment: This is guaranteed to throw an exception as soon as `i` reaches `len(some_list)-3`.

Comment: How about `thing and (some_list[i+1] if i+1 < len(some_list) else True) and (`…? (To avoid having to type that out 3 times, I'd write a function that wraps it…)

Comment: @abarnert (1) That's horribly convulted. (2) I don't see how the previous version is wrong. A sliced copy is passed to enumerate, but the list not modified, so `some_list` has 3 items more than `enumerate` sees...

Comment: @delnan: I'm not sure which previous version you're referring to. The one that was there at the point I wrote my comment was definitely wrong. At any rate, what's there now works, but it has completely different effects from what I suggested, so you can't choose between them based on which is more convoluted; you have to figure out which one fits the problem you're actually trying to solve. (In other words, do you want to look at some_list[-2] even though it doesn't have three following values, or does it automatically fail because it doesn't have three following values?)

Comment: @abarnert The version I'm referring to is archived as "first" revision when clicking the "edited <timespan> ago" link. And I'm not saying your suggestion is horrible compared to this one (for reasons you cited), I'm saying it's horrible period -- there must be a more readable way to achieve that.

Comment: @delnan: There have been a lot more than 2 versions here… When I commented, it was just `for i, thing in enumerate(some_list):` and then it used `some_list[i+3]`.

Comment: @delnan: Meanwhile, anything which tries to deal with the next 3 elements is going to be 3x as ugly as anything that deals with the next 1 element. (In fact, if I had to deal with anything more than 1, I'd make it deal with an arbitrary N, which might be more complicated, but should be less ugly—as well as more flexible, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question properly, what you're trying to do is exactly the same thing as `str.find`, but looking for a sublist within a list instead of a substring within a string.

If so:

```
def findSubList(l, sub):
  return (''.join('T' if x else 'F' for x in l)
          .find(''.join('T' if x else 'F' for x in sub)))
```

This may seem hacky, but it makes sense: You want to find a sub-list within a list, both can be trivially converted to strings, and there's already a built-in function to find a sub-string within a string, so why not use it?

It may turn out to be too slow, but really, it's so fast to code this up that it's worth testing it to see if it's too slow for your purposes. (And even if it is too slow, it's probably the convert-to-string part that's slow, and it may be reasonable to just use strings instead of lists of bools in the first place, or convert once at the start before doing 200 searches, or whatever.)

If this is unavoidably too slow, the next thing I'd do is look at the implementation of `str.find` and convert it to a generic sequence find. You've got the source to Python, so this shouldn't be too hard. However, it is possible that `str.find` is in C, which might be painful to port. In that case, you still might want to search for a pure Python `str.find` online… but let's assume you don't find one.

The next step is to see if there's a sequence find module on PyPI.

If not, there are a handful of well-known algorithms that are either easy to implement, or have free implementations at places like ActiveState or even Wikipedia. See [String searching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) at Wikipedia for a list, and some comparisons. (The performance characteristics depend on factors that you haven't given us—how many searches you need to do; whether main, subset, or both vary; etc., which means nobody can guess which one will be best without more information.)

It's possible that even the standard string search algorithms aren't fast enough, and there are major efficiency gains to be had by taking advantage of the fact that you're searching single bits instead of 8-bit characters. (If the pattern is fixed, you should even be able to describe the search as a finite state machine and turn that into a hard-coded, provably optimal implementation…)

So, you *may* have to design something yourself. But it's very unlikely that you will, and I would avoid doing so if at all possible. Whenever you've got a problem this obviously common, it's worth assuming that it's a solved problem and looking for solutions, rather than trying to solve it from first principles.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly efficient, uses a sliding window approach, should run in linear time.

```
def find_x_in_y(subset, main):
    """ Returns a list of the indexes of the first value of matches. """
    results = []
    for i in xrange(len(main)):
        if main[i:i+5] == subset:
              results.append(i)
    return results

# values borrowed from @JonClements
subset = [True, True, False, True, True]
main = [False, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True]

>>> find_x_in_y(subset, main)
... [4]
```

@abarnert Fine, here's an *actually* extremely efficient approach.

Extremely efficient, transforms the entire bool list to a bitarray and runs the native search method.

```
from bitarray import bitarray

def find_x_in_y(subset, main):
    subarray = bitarray(subset)
    mainarray = bitarray(main)
    return [int(i) for i in mainarray.itersearch(subarray)]
```

`timeit` results:

```
Length of main:                     10      100     1000    10000   100000   1000000

returning _all_ matches:
# number of matches                  1       10      100     1000    10000    100000
# sliding window approach     (0.00059, 0.00502, 0.04194, 0.26211, 2.55554, 26.21962)
# bitarray approach           (0.00028, 0.00072, 0.00484, 0.02926, 0.2822,   2.93676)

returning first match:
# sliding window approach     (0.00034, 0.00034, 0.00034, 0.00021, 0.00026,  0.00059)
# bitarray approach           (0.00017, 0.00017, 0.00016, 0.00011, 0.00014,  0.00049)
# joined string approach      (0.00134, 0.00721, 0.06244, 0.39224, 4.21628, 39.63207)
```

Comment: This makes 4 un-necessary comparisons though: `[False, True, False, True], [True, False, True], [False, True], [True]`

Comment: If by "should run in linear time" you mean linear in len(main), yes, the code runs in linear time because `main[i:i+5]` limits the number of element comparisons to at most 5.  If you correct `main[i:i+5]` to `main[i:i+len(subset)]` or equivalent, then it becomes obvious that the method is O(len(main) * len(subset)).

Comment: @JonClements `xrange(len(main))` rewritten as `xrange(len(main)-4)` is pointless over what is supposedly a **very long** list of booleans. :)

@jwpat which is still linear? I don't understand your point.  Give me a sec to further optimize it.

Comment: @kreativitea: jwpat's point is that it's `O(NM)`, which is only really linear if `M` is fixed/small. A Boyer-Moore search is `O(N+M)`, which is clearly better if `M` is potentially large.

Comment: Meanwhile, discussions of efficiency are meaningless without knowing how this is going to be used. Will it be called many times with the same `main` but different `subset` values? With the same `subset` but different `main`? With both different? Is `subset` always very small compared to `main`? If both values are always small and it's only run once, of course, performance doesn't even matter at all, and the best answer is whatever's easiest to read and write.

Comment: @abarnert Fair enough, but due to the wording of the question, I felt assuming that the subset was small, if not outright fixed, was the specification.  I'll hope the OP will elucidate further.

Comment: You've described your code as "extremely efficient", and I don't think that's accurate. It's effectively the standard naive search; you don't do any skipping at all. So, even for a fixed 5-len subset, I'll bet many of the simple well-known algorithms will average about 2-3x as fast.

Comment: There is _no_ general-purpose search algorithm that's "extremely efficient" for all use cases. So, even without checking what algorithm `bitarray.itersearch` uses, I already know that you can't call it extremely efficient without knowing what the actual use case is… And after looking at it, it's basically the naive algorithm, with the added overhead of having to mask bits one by one, so it's probably slower than yours. Native != efficient.

Comment: @abarnert For a boolean array, the naive way is the best way.  Any kind of skipping or seeking involves looking through the array, you might as well do the comparison.  String searching is built for just that-- string searches, which may or may not have more than two values, and therefore skipping and seeking have a significant impact on performance.  Why are you making things more complicated than they are?  This is not about a general purpose search algorithm, this is about a search algorithm for a **boolean array**.

Comment: You can skip N bits ahead without any additional work except a single mod, and it can obviously be useful to do so. Meanwhile, converting each bool to a bit instead of an integer is inherently such a huge pessimization that it will blow away any benefits, and the fact that the algorithm does bit-by-bit comparisons instead of masking `(N+offset)%8` bits at a time makes it even slower.